# Dell r730 + Dell 12Gb SAS + Centos 7 + netvault 9.2 quantum superloader 3 not found

Tags: linux, centos, dell, sas, netvault

In the above configuration Netvault does not find the library attached to the sas controller.
What driver should I see with lsmod for the SAS card?
I have:

```
...
mpt3sas               195379  0 
libahci                32009  1 ahci
tg3                   170669  0 
libata                218854  2 ahci,libahci
raid_class             13554  1 mpt3sas
i2c_core               40325  4 drm,drm_kms_helper,mgag200,i2c_algo_bit
scsi_transport_sas     41034  1 mpt3sas
...
```

But mpt3sas they seem related the the PERC raid controller, correct?
lspci gives

```
...
03:00.0 RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS-3 3108 [Invader] (rev 02)
06:00.0 Serial Attached SCSI controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic SAS3008 PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS-3 (rev 02)
...
```

What can I do to further debug this problem?
Thanks,
Nico